# Does MS XBOX Kinect have some Silverlight underneath?

Tags: silverlight, xbox360, kinect

I've heard rumors that the latest game console from Microsoft (Kinect) was built partly with using some Silverlight constructs - is this true?  I can't find any documentation on it.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no connection between Silverlight and Kinect. Kinect is essentially a 3D camera which is pretty good at detecting depth. After some processing on the raw data, it outputs the 3D model.

Silverlight is something which operates at the UI level and not such deep hardware level. It is possible that at some point Silverlight comes to the Xbox 360 and will be able to use Kinect as an input.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Microsoft console is still XBox 360... Kinect is just an gaming accessory like gamepad or driving weel.

And yes, you can develop application for XBox using XNA framework. Silverlight is coming soon.

http://blogs.iis.net/benwagg/archive/2009/06/25/silverlight-on-xbox-360-demo-at-cannes.aspx